# How to use generator in os find function like wrapper?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, generator

I have a function in python which works like `find` command. So basically it will go into depth till it hit `m_depth` **(maxdepth)** and will not go into the directory if it is specified in `ignore_dirs`. It will return a list of files which is found in a `walk`. The code is really simple and uses recursion.

But for a large number of files or greater depth, the recursion is taking time and the list is getting bigger when returning. So I am seeking if anyway the generator can be used, so atleast the memory consumption is less for each iteration?

I tried with `yield`ing the result but then it is exiting whenever a `ignore_dirs` is found.

This is the code I have:

```
def find(source_d, m_depth, ignore_dirs):
    '''
    This method does a recursive listing of files/directories from a given 
    path upto maximun recursion value provide as m_depth.

    :param source_d: Given source path to start the recursion from
    :param m_depth: Maximum recursion depth [determines how deep the method will traverse through the file system]
    :param ignore_dirs: this paths will not be traversed. List of strings. 
    '''

    def helper_find(path, ignore_dirs, m_depth, curr_depth=1):
        files = []
        if any(ignore_sub_dir == os.path.split(path)[-1] for ignore_sub_dir in ignore_dirs):
            return []

        if m_depth < curr_depth:
            return []

        else:
            things = os.listdir(path)

            for thing in things:
                if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, thing))):
                    files.extend(helper_find(os.path.join(path, thing), ignore_dirs, m_depth, curr_depth+1))

                else:
                    files.append(os.path.join(path, thing))

        return files

    return helper_find(source_d, ignore_dirs, m_depth)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can make a recursive generator by using [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) (available only in Python 3):

```
def find(source_d, m_depth, ignore_dirs):
    '''
    This method does a recursive listing of files/directories from a given
    path upto maximun recursion value provide as m_depth.

    :param source_d: Given source path to start the recursion from
    :param m_depth: Maximum recursion depth [determines how deep the method will traverse through the file system]
    :param ignore_dirs: this paths will not be traversed. List of strings.
    '''
    def helper_find(path, ignore_dirs, m_depth, curr_depth=1):
        if not any(ignore_sub_dir == os.path.split(path)[-1] for ignore_sub_dir in ignore_dirs)and m_depth >= curr_depth:

            things = os.listdir(path)

            for thing in things:
                if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, thing))):
                    yield from helper_find(os.path.join(path, thing), ignore_dirs, m_depth, curr_depth+1)

                else:
                    yield os.path.join(path, thing)

    return helper_find(source_d, ignore_dirs, m_depth)
```

Comment: The problem with `any(ignore_sub_dir in path...` is suppose I don't want to go into `videos` dir. So I will pass `ignore_dirs` as `["videos","some"]`. Now I don't want to go into `videos` which is present under the source path *only*. What if source path itself contains `videos`.. then at first step it will return. Hope you are getting my point.... Though I have unit-tested my code for various scenarios and I didn't get any bug.

Comment: There is some extra empty list returning which is throwing my testcase off. Can returning extra empty list be removed?

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' you're returning an empty list in the first `if` condition, try the updated version above (where this `if` is removed)